# Java EE UriInfo: append Query parameters

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, uri

I want to append the query parameters list of a received UriInfo in a Rest service. The query comes from the client with some parameters and I need to add some more in server side.

I tried with:

```
uriInfo.getQueryParameters().add("Param", "value");
```

but when I display the URI, it doesn't has the new parameter.

On the other hand, if I do it like this:

```
URI uri = uriInfo.getRequestUriBuilder().queryParam("Param", "value").build();
```

when I display the URI, it contains the new parameter. The problem in this second case is to reconstruct a UriInfo object to give to the next functions, they require it.

I've seen that it cannot be instantiated, it has no constructors, it has to be added with @Context, its value can be updated by another UriInfo... but how to create this UriInfo with the URI I modified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to modify a UriInfo, there are no methods defined for that. The only option is to recreate it using one implementation of the interface. The only implementation available is org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyUriInfo.

The problem is that when deployed, and the function using it is called, it throws a ClassDefNotFound exception; even with a dependency in the manifest pointing to resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar

So, the only option is to make our own implementation of the interface.